# Which is better leaving group out of iodide and water?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, nucleophilicity

In hydrolysis reaction of an tertiary alkyl halide , $\ce{H_2O}$ will replace the $\ce{I-}$ through $\ce{S_N1}$ mechanism and then $\ce{H+}$ will be removed from $\ce{H_2O}$ in order to form an alcohol.

But in the reaction of an alcohol with $\ce{HI}$ , the water leaves as leaving group and $\ce{I-}$ act as an nucleophile replacing $\ce{H2O}$.

So both reactions seems contradicting to me , even the solvent in both case is polar protic , So what actually favours the reaction in a particular direction?

Comment: It is probably the concentrations of the various reagents that is the major force in pushing the equilibrium in one direction or the other. For example, when you are hydrolysing something in the lab, you add a whole lot of water and a small amount of reagent. Whereas when you are reacting alcohol with HI, you would probably use a lot of HI with a small amount of the reactant (though I have never done this particular reaction in lab)

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti I also thought upon it  , but can't seem to get how the concentration of reagents will affect  whether Water will replace Iodide or vice-versa ?

Comment: The reaction is an equilibrium—when you add one reagent in excess, the reaction is pushed towards the opposite side (Le Chatelier). When water is in excess, the reaction goes towards the alcohol and free iodide and vice versa.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti Thanks ! It seems right , though can you tell which side is favoured thermodynamically , I mean which direction has ΔG < 0 ?

Comment: That is hard to say without looking at experimental data.